# Dynamically change schema of DB SQLAlchemy instance

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask App which uses multiple schemas on the same MySQL database. Each schema has the same tables with the same structure and it represents a different "instance" used by the app for different accounts connecting to the application.

Is it possible to dynamically tell the db object which schema to use?

Comment: Hey, did you find if you could dynamically tell the db object which schema to use?

Answer (score 1):

In order to follow SO rules I will also paste here the relevant part of the Flask-SQLAlchemy documentation on the topic.

> **Multiple Databases with Binds**
>
> Starting with 0.12 Flask-SQLAlchemy can
>   easily connect to multiple databases. To achieve that it preconfigures
>   SQLAlchemy to support multiple “binds”.
>
> What are binds? In SQLAlchemy speak a bind is something that can
>   execute SQL statements and is usually a connection or engine. In
>   Flask-SQLAlchemy binds are always engines that are created for you
>   automatically behind the scenes. Each of these engines is then
>   associated with a short key (the bind key). This key is then used at
>   model declaration time to assocate a model with a specific engine.
>
> If no bind key is specified for a model the default connection is used
>   instead (as configured by SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI).
>
> **Example Configuration**
>
> The following configuration declares three
>   database connections. The special default one as well as two others
>   named users (for the users) and appmeta (which connects to a sqlite
>   database for read only access to some data the application provides
>   internally):

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgres://localhost/main'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'users':        'mysqldb://localhost/users',
    'appmeta':      'sqlite:////path/to/appmeta.db'
}
```

> **Creating and Dropping Tables**
>
> The create_all() and drop_all() methods by default operate on all declared binds, including the
>   default one. This behavior can be customized by providing the bind
>   parameter. It takes either a single bind name, '**all**' to refer to
>   all binds or a list of binds. The default bind
>   (SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI) is named None:

```
>>> db.create_all()
>>> db.create_all(bind=['users'])
>>> db.create_all(bind='appmeta')
>>> db.drop_all(bind=None)
```

> **Referring to Binds**
>
> If you declare a model you can specify the bind to use with the **bind_key** attribute:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

> Internally the bind key is stored in the table’s info dictionary as
>   'bind_key'. This is important to know because when you want to create
>   a table object directly you will have to put it in there:

```
user_favorites = db.Table('user_favorites',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('message_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('message.id')),
    info={'bind_key': 'users'}
)
```

> If you specified the **bind_key** on your models you can use them
>   exactly the way you are used to. The model connects to the specified
>   database connection itself.

Here's link to [Official Documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/)

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer! Unfortunately, I don't think that this is a viable solution, because the binds themselves can change dynamically after the app and the DB instance has been initialized.